# vim can not set shiftwidth and tabstop with ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/coffeescript.vim

Tags: vim, coffeescript, indentation

I want to set `shiftwidth` and `tabstop` with `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/coffeescript.vim` as follow:

```
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal tabstop=2
```

but this does not work, I have test with `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`, this does work.

Comment: In a coffeescript file, enter `:verbose set sw?` to find out, where it was set last

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, did you copy paste the path to your settings file? I noticed that there's a typo in "coffescirpt.vim", is that how the file is spelled?